# Waits for one of two xpaths to be present, one inside of an iframe, one outside of it

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm using selenium for testing, and I've written code that waits for one of two locations before it continues. This is really easy when both locations are within the same frame, because then I can just use a WebDriverWait, which is the obvious solution. That's not the case for this situation though.

This is the basic idea of the elements I'm trying to find

```
<div>Location outside of IFrame</div>
<iframe>
  #document
    <html>
      <div>Location inside of IFrame</div>
```

Here's the working code I currently have

```
ChromeDriver driver;
bool isPresent = false;

// This resets the start time for a timer.
StartTimer();

// HasMinutesPassed is a method that returns false until x minutes have passed.
while (!HasMinutesPassed(2) && !isPresent) 
{
    if (driver.FindElements(iFrameLocation).Any())
    {
        //This is an extension method in my project that makes IFrame handling a bit easier. I'll include the method just in case it's what's stopping this from being better
        driver.ExecuteInFrame(iFrameLocation, () =>
        {
            // insideLocation is the XPath for the element I'm looking for inside of the iFrame
            if (driver.FindElements(insideLocation).Any())
            {
                isPresent = true;
            }
        });
    }
    
    // outsideLocation is the XPath for the element I'm looking for outside of the iFrame
    if (driver.FindElements(outsideLocation).Any())
    {
        isPresent = true;
    }
}

// Iframe handling method
public void ExecuteInFrame(this Driver driver, By frameLocator, Action action)
{
    driver.Instance.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
    driver.Wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(frameLocator));
    action();
    driver.Instance.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
}
```

I know it's probably inefficient, and it almost definitely could be cleaner. Any suggestions on how to improve this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: there is not much to review, current code seems fine to me, but if you see that an extension method would be useful across the project, then go for it. also `ExecuteInFrame` perhaps a `frameLocator` extension would be better than `driver` extension (if possible).

Comment: Could you please fix your code? `ExecuteInFrame` should be `static` otherwise it is not an extension method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By reducing the number of `if` blocks you can greatly simplify your code.

- This guarded assignment

```
if (driver.FindElements(outsideLocation).Any())
{
    isPresent = true;
}
```

- is equal to this

```
isPresent = driver.FindElements(outsideLocation).Any();
```

So, if you apply this change and use `do - while` loop instead of `while` then your main logic could be written like this

```
do
{
    if (driver.FindElements(iFrameLocation).Any())      
        driver.ExecuteInFrame(iFrameLocation, () => isPresent = driver.FindElements(insideLocation).Any());
          
    isPresent = driver.FindElements(outsideLocation).Any();

} while (!HasMinutesPassed(2) && !isPresent)
```

---

By introducing the following helper method

```
bool IsElementPresent(By by) => driver.FindElements(by).Any();
```

you can make your code even more concise

```
do
{
    if (IsElementPresent(iFrameLocation))      
        driver.ExecuteInFrame(iFrameLocation,
            () => isPresent = IsElementPresent(insideLocation));
          
    isPresent = IsElementPresent(outsideLocation);

} while (!HasMinutesPassed(2) && !isPresent)
```

Comment: OOOO That looks so much nicer!